Add checkbox field to core/embed
I want to add checkbox to core/embed,
I ahave tried many solutions , non work
for example , one of my essays
Update : addng any field would be appreciated
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',  // The filter hook to modify block registration
    'misha/oembed',              // A unique name for this modification
    (settings, name) => {
        // Check if the block name is 'core/embed'
        if ('core/embed' === name) {
            
            // Add custom 'custom_text_field' attribute
            return lodash.assign({}, settings, {
                attributes: lodash.assign({}, settings.attributes, {
                    custom_text_field: {
                        type: 'string', // Type of the attribute (string)
                        default: '',    // Default value for the text field (empty string)
                    }
                })
            });
        }
        
        // Return the settings unmodified if it's not 'core/embed'
        return settings;
    }
);

I have found this code maybe useful
function addCustomAttributes( settings, name ) {
    if ( settings.attributes ) {
        settings.attributes.customAttribute = {
            type: 'string',
            default: ''
        };

        settings.attributes.anotherCustomAttribute = {
            type: 'boolean',
            default: false
        };
    }
    return settings;
}


what will this checkbox do and where would it appear? Would it not be easier to create a style/wrapper/variant?

Any solution will be apprecaited , even add text field , it will add _blank

can you answer the first question I asked? Why you want to do this and the purpose of the checkbox are important, it's very difficult to make a suggestion otherwise

I want to add checkbox to choose whether when to click open in new window or not

I have found this code maybe useful

it's not enough to add an attribute as that won't create any user interface, you'll also need PHP code to handle the attribute since an OEmbed is usually an iframe of some sorts, it would need wrapping somehow. I think instead a block style would work better for you as that would let you add a CSS class that could be checked for in PHP to modify the blocks output

any code snippet would be helpful , and I try to adjust it
